# digital electronics circuit delay- how to find setup time?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, delay, homework

How to find setup time for this 'd' register?

In my opinion, Tsetup=T_I5+T_I6+T_T1+T_I1 but not sure if to include T_T3 next of T_I2 next? which path would we take?

[image]

Comment: Do you know that is a 'd' register? Do you know how a 'd' register works? A hint is that whatever tsu is going in at TT1, it's that + TG5 + TG6 going in at the input. Draw a diagram of all the waveforms, aligned temporally, and the tsu will become apparent.

Comment: We don't just hand out answers to homework questions here. Show significant effort to solve this problem yourself. Tell us what you **do** understand about the problem and explain exactly where you get stuck.

Comment: @shzl Do not add your additional information within comments. Edit your question and put the explanations there.

Comment: At the instant in time when setup matters, what is the state of CK? Which transmission gates are conducting and which are not? You can't be concerned about delay through a non-conducting Tgate. What electrical condition do you want to satisfy before the clock changes?